# Windows Service connection to SQL Server over internet

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-services

I have created a windows service and want to connect to SQL server 2008 over internet.  The issue is that although I can connect it locally and with the local IP, my server is behind a firewall.  Since there is a Sharepoint server on the web on the same server, I know that the system is on the internet.

What should be the connection string to connect to the server from outside the local network and from anywhere in the world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's behind a firewall, you'll have to open port 1433 to incoming traffic.  Other than that, the connection string should be the same as the internal one, only using the external IP (if you don't know it: http://www.whatsmyip.org/).  You'll need to make sure that mixed authentication is enabled, because of course you can't connect using Windows domain credentials over the internet.

I should probably mention it's not a very good practice to expose your SQL Server to the outside world ... but you know that, right?

Comment: Thankyou. Yes i know it is not a good practice but i have time constraints and i need to get it running. Can you suggest me any other secure method to do this. My service will be installed on clients that are remotely scattered.

Comment: note that the port number could be different in case of a named instance or because it was changed in the server config.

Comment: Different port numbers don't help a lot. Id suggest that he setup a https proxy tunnel to access the sql server if he really needs to access the server directly.

Comment: @UzairShahid Well, the best thing would be to set up a VPN for your clients to connect to.  If you can't do that, then you could consider at least using a non-standard port for the server.